# No results label on empty tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am adding "No results" label if `tableView` is empty.

```
extension UITableView {
    override open func layoutSubviews() {
        print("Table layoutSubviews")
        let label = UILabel(frame: self.bounds)
        if self.visibleCells.isEmpty {
            label.center = self.center
            label.text = "No Results"
            label.textAlignment = .center
            if label.superview == nil {
                self.addSubview(label)
            }
        } else {
            label.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work on updating/Reloading `tableView`(on row change).
It still show "No Result" on non empty `UITableView`

Comment: Are you calling this extension while updating/Reloading your `tableView`?

Comment: No it automatically calls, as `layoutSubviews` is under `UIView` life cycle. I am trying to make DRY code.

Comment: Obviously layout subviews doesn't know the cells are visible or not yet. Instead check your data source to see if the table is empty.

Comment: @Desdenova Yes, but where or which lifeCycle method to use ?

Comment: @Ramesh I'd use a regular table cell and use it if the data source is empty. No need to override things and hack the ui.

Comment: @Desdenova for that case we may have to write code for many Cells. because table can contain difrrent type of cells.

Answer (score 4):

```
extension UITableView {

    func setMessage(_ message: String) {
        let lblMessage = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.size.width, height: self.bounds.size.height))
        lblMessage.text = message
        lblMessage.textColor = .black
        lblMessage.numberOfLines = 0
        lblMessage.textAlignment = .center
        lblMessage.font = UIFont(name: "TrebuchetMS", size: 15)
        lblMessage.sizeToFit()

        self.backgroundView = lblMessage
        self.separatorStyle = .none
    }

    func clearBackground() {
        self.backgroundView = nil
        self.separatorStyle = .singleLine
    }
}
```

Now use this extension as like below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if items.count == 0 {
        tableView.setMessage("No results")
    } else {
        tableView.clearBackground()
    }

    return items.count
}
```

Comment: Any chance using auto call ? since i am using extension.

Comment: although it works. but i am looking for generic function, which calls automatically with lifecycle method.

Comment: it worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create Swift Class With Name "TableViewHelper".
You Can also Used In a CollectionView.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewHelper {

    class func EmptyMessage(message:String, tableview:UITableView,vc:UIViewController) {
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), size: CGSize(width: vc.view.bounds.size.width, height: vc.view.bounds.size.height))
    let messageLabel = UILabel(frame: rect)
    messageLabel.text = message
    messageLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    messageLabel.textAlignment = .center
    messageLabel.font = UIFont(name: "TrebuchetMS", size: 15)
    messageLabel.sizeToFit()

    tableview.backgroundView = messageLabel;
    tableview.separatorStyle = .none;
    }
}

class ColelctionViewHelper {

    class func EmptyMessage(message:String, collectionview:UICollectionView,vc:UIViewController) {
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), size: CGSize(width: vc.view.bounds.size.width, height: vc.view.bounds.size.height))
    let messageLabel = UILabel(frame: rect)
    messageLabel.text = message
    messageLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    messageLabel.textAlignment = .center
    messageLabel.font = UIFont(name: "TrebuchetMS", size: 15)
    messageLabel.sizeToFit()

    collectionview.backgroundView = messageLabel;
   // collectionview.separatorStyle = .none;
    }
}
```

This Is How You Use It,

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
  if YourArray.count>0{
            TableViewHelper.EmptyMessage(message: "", tableview: TableName,vc: self)
            return EventArray.count
        }else{
            TableViewHelper.EmptyMessage(message: "No Results", tableview: TableName,vc: self)
            return 0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try the solution of adding label to background of tableview, but the behaviour of label looks weird when we scroll empty tableview. I also tried to stop scrolling behaviour of tableview but that doesn't work when the tableview array is not empty.
So i tried another solution which worked perfectly just like what i want.

```
// MARK: - TableView Delegate Functions
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "No data to show"
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)
    label.textColor = .gray
    label.textAlignment = .center
    
    if dataArray.count == 0 {
        return label
    }
    return nil
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if dataArray.count == 0 {
        return 250 // According to requirement
    }
    return 0
}
```

### Note

Don't forget to call `tableView.reloadData()` after update your dataArray.